# Async slower than Sync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await, .net-4.5

I have been working on Async calls and I found that the Async version of a method is running much slower than the Sync version. Can anyone comment on what I may be missing. Thanks.

### Statistics

Sync method time is 00:00:23.5673480

Async method time is 00:01:07.1628415

Total Records/Entries returned per call = 19972

Below is the code that i am running.

-------------------- Test class ----------------------

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestPeoplePerformanceSyncVsAsync()
{
    DateTime start;
    DateTime end;

    start = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    using (IPersonRepository repository = kernel.Get<IPersonRepository>())
    {
        IList<IPerson> people1 = repository.GetPeople();
        IList<IPerson> people2 = repository.GetPeople();
    }
    }
    end = DateTime.Now;
    var diff = start - end;
    Console.WriteLine(diff);

    start = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    using (IPersonRepository repository = kernel.Get<IPersonRepository>())
    {
        Task<IList<IPerson>> people1 = GetPeopleAsync();
        Task<IList<IPerson>> people2 = GetPeopleAsync();
        Task.WaitAll(new Task[] {people1, people2});
    }
    }
    end = DateTime.Now;
    diff = start - end;
    Console.WriteLine(diff);
}

private async Task<IList<IPerson>> GetPeopleAsync()
{
    using (IPersonRepository repository = kernel.Get<IPersonRepository>())
    {
    return await repository.GetPeopleAsync();
    }
}
```

-------------------------- Repository ----------------------------

```
    public IList<IPerson> GetPeople()
    {
        List<IPerson> people = new List<IPerson>();
        using (PersonContext context = new PersonContext())
        {
            people.AddRange(context.People);
        }
        return people;
    }

    public async Task<IList<IPerson>> GetPeopleAsync()
    {
        List<IPerson> people = new List<IPerson>();
        using (PersonContext context = new PersonContext())
        {
            people.AddRange(await context.People.ToListAsync());
        }
        return people;
    }
```

Comment: The purpose of using asynchrony is not strictly to improve performance.

Comment: I am not c# specialist, but I think that "await" should not be used in both `GetPeopleAsync` methods, as it suspends the execution and the methods are actually not async. The only suspending must be by `Task.WaitAll`.

Comment: I agree, but the results shouldn't be that far apart, particularly when the data is not small.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov That's incorrect.  The `await` there is entirely appropriate.

Comment: I agreed to Servy, I dont know whats wrong with you guys... I posted but i guess again sync fault... Alex's post just came before me while posting...

Comment: @SajidQ: To address the down-votes again. Please read this blog post by Jon Skeet: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx It is frequently referenced and recommended when SOers ask a question and encounter a lot of down-votes that seem unjustified.

Answer (score 5):

So we've got a whole *bunch* of issues here, so I'll just say right off the bat that this isn't going to be an exhaustive list.

First off, the *point* of asynchrony is not strictly to improve performance.  It can be, in certain contexts, used to improve performance, but that's not *necessarily* its goal.  It can also be used to keep a UI responsive, for example.  *Paralleization* is usually used to increase performance, but parallelization and asynchrony aren't equivalent.  On top of *that*, parallelization has an overhead.  You're spending time creating threads, scheduling them, synchronizing data between them, etc.  The benefit of performing some operations in parallel may or may not surpass this overhead.  If it doesn't, a synchronous solution may well be more performant.

Next, your "asynchronous" example isn't asynchronous "all the way up".  You're calling `WaitAll` on the tasks inside the loop.  For the example to be properly asynchronous one would like to see it be asynchronous all the way up to a *single* operation, namely some form of message loop.

Next, the two aren't don't the exact same thing in an asynchronous and synchronous manor.  They are *doing different things*, which will obviously affect performance:

- Your "asynchronous" solution creates 3 repositories.  Your synchronous solution creates one.  There is going to be some overhead here.
- `GetPeopleAsync` takes a list, then pulls all of the items out of the list and puts them into *another* list.  That's unnecessary overhead.

Then there are problems with your benchmarking:

- You're using `DateTime.Now`, which is not designed for timing how long an operation takes.  it's precision isn't particularly high, for example.  You should use a `StopWatch` to time how long code takes.
- You aren't performing all that many iterations.  There's plenty of opportunity for the variation to affect the results here.
- You aren't accounting for the fact that the first few runs through a section of code will take longer.  The JITter needs to "warm up".
- Garbage collections can be affecting your timings, namely that the objects created in the first test can end up being cleaned up during the second test.

Comment: Thanks Servy, I believe you have raised valid points, particularly the Repository instantiation. However, total time for sync vs async for the same method ideally shouldn't be that much apart.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on your data, or rather the amount of it. You didn't post what test metrics you're using to run your tests but this is my experience:

Usually when you see a slowdown in the performance of parallel algorithms when you're expecting improvement it's that the overhead of loading the extra libraries and spawning threads etc. slows down the parallel algorithm and makes it look like the linear/single-threaded version is performing better.

A greater amount of data should show better performance. Also try running the same test twice when all the libraries are loaded to avoid the load overhead.

If you don't see improvement, something is seriously wrong.

**Note**: You're getting voted down, I'm guessing, because you posted much more code than context, metrics etc. in the OP. IMO, very few SOers will actually bother to read and grok even that much code without being able to execute it while also being presented with metrics that are not at all useful!

Why I didn't read the code: When I see a code block with scroll bars along with the kind of text that was present in the original OP, my brain says: Don't bother. I think many if not most, probably do this.

Things to try:

- Two different synch times does not mean statistically significant data. You should run each algorithm a number of times (5 at least) to see if you're experiencing anomalies. If your results for the same algorithms vary wildly then you may have other issues such as bandwidth restriction, server load etc. and the issue is external.
- Try a .NET memory performance and/or memory profiler to help you track down the issue.
- See @servy's great answer for more clues. It seems that he actually took the time to look at your code more closely.

Comment: Whats the reason of -2?FYI, the data is big, I am getting 19972 entries of Person object used in AdventureWorks 2012.

Comment: Well, if I posted the question only, I would be voted down again because of not posting code. And the code that I have posted should be sufficient enough to look at the problem, if any.

Comment: @SajidQ: The number of entries of Person objects is the important metric. Two different synch times is not a statistically significant data. You should mention it in your OP. You could also shave down the code, if at all possible.

Comment: The size of the list is likely not of significant importance at all.  The fact that he's going across the network to get the data, even if there isn't much of it, is going to take quite some time.

Comment: I don't see why you're suggesting removing some of the code.  There's not all that much, the majority of it is very simple, but *all* of it is relevant.  I cannot imagine cutting any of it out without removing important information highly relevant to an answer.  If you don't have the time to actually look at the code then you really shouldn't be answering the question.  Your answer demonstrates that you didn't really bother, making your advice not useful.

Comment: @servy: Honestly, if I hadn't any experience with this kind of situation I would have voted down and voted to close and moved on. I think most SOers would. I'm surprised that you stopped to read through all the code given the way the OP was: The original OP just looked like: "Hey, find my bug. Here's the code." +1 On your answer and commentary btw.

Comment: @servy: Also consider the breadth of issues that your answer and mine cover. It's questions like these that are most often closed as too broad, or low quality or some such... IMHO.

Comment: @PaulSasik If you think that the question is too broad, then by all means, vote to close.  If you think that the question warrants downvoting, by all means, vote it down.  But trying to a question about a code block without even taking the time to read it, when it's only one screen's worth of text, is something to be pretty wary of.  I don't consider just a few dozen lines to be "way too much code".  The question about that code should ideally be more focused, yes, but the code itself is almost ideal in including what is relevant and omitting what isn't.

Comment: @Servy: We obviously have two different points of view. I didn't down-vote or vote to close because the OP seems to be a n00b and I stopped and gave a broad answer, along with some ideas as to why the OP was drawing so many down-votes, to try to help him/her out. For the amount of code... The original text leading up to the code biased me and I was not going to bother reading it and play "find my bug." I honestly think that's most of what the down-voters did. You seem to have much more patience and skill for reading code. I hope the OP appreciates your efforts.

Comment: @PaulSasik, nothing personal but it appears from your response that instead of helping others, you are looking to increase your rate of answering questions/day. So, what you are looking for is probably questions like "1+1=?" so that you can answer 2 and move on. Maybe this site is about such questions, I don't know.

Comment: However, let me clarify that this question is not about "Heres the code, find bugs". Nor is it "1+1=?" obviously. This is more about "I am experiencing this issue, has anyone else experienced it? If yes, could you please provide your findings to save my time. Besides, I am continuing my investigation anyway." Probably, my "Can anyone comment on what I may be missing." wasn't direct enough. But I will seek advice from other sites for that now.

Comment: @SajidQ: I am completely puzzled that you think that despite my efforts on this post you think I'm just looking to pad my stats somehow. I am not looking for easy questions to answer. I shared with you my own honest, gut-level reaction to your OP and tried to explain my opinion on why you were getting so many down-votes. Like it or not, presentation matters a great deal on SO in questions as well as answers. It's supposed to be a cut and dry Q/A site about programming, but it is run by humans, many impatient. Please re-read my answer and comments. The criticism was meant to be constructive.